# Ошибка при открытии файла, заданного как аргумент командной строки

Tags: linux, c, fopen

Задание, которое мне необходимо выполнить: создать программу, которая будет суммировать матрицы, содержание которых описано в текстовом файле. В качестве аргументов командной строки задаются к-во матриц (1й аргумент), к-во строк (второй) и столбцов (третий). Далее идет ключ, определяющий, в каком порядке будут считываться числа в текстовом файле. И в конце название текстового файла, в который записаны числа.

В чем проблема: Компилятор на код не ругается, проверка аргументов выполняется, но ошибка возникает еще в момент открытия файла: при каждом запуске программы на экран выводится "Cannot open the file" и все. В чем может быть проблема?

Высылаю полный код программы. Если есть другие существенные ошибки - не против о них услышать.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* arrayBuf;
char* buffer;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    //Checking the number of arguments
    assert(argc == 5 || argc == 6);
    
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    int m = atoi(argv[3]);
    
    //Checking if the arguments are right
    if(k <= 1 || n < 1 || m < 1){
        printf("Check your arguments!\nThey cannot be less than 1 (k also cannot be 1)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Variable for the number of needed number of numbers
    int count = k * n * m;
    int numbers[count];
    
    //Option
    bool f1 = false;
    int ch;
    ch = getopt(argc, argv, "Z");
    switch(ch){
        case 'Z':
            f1 = true;
            break;
                
        case '?':
            printf("Invalid option\n");
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    //Opening the file
    FILE *fp;
    
    char* name;
    if (f1 = true) name = argv[5];
    else name = argv[4];
    
    if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open the file\n");
        return 2;
    }
    
    //Reading the file
    else {
        
        //Offset for ftell()
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        
        //Setting the size of buffer
        long size = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        
        if (buffer == NULL){
            printf("Cannot create the buffer\n");
            return 3;
        }
        
        //Reading the file
        fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), size, fp);
        arrayBuf = strtok(buffer, " ");
        
        //Checking if the chars are integers
        while (arrayBuf != NULL){
            int c = 0;
            numbers[c] = atoi(arrayBuf);
            c ++;
            
            bool f2 = false;
            if(arrayBuf[0] == '-' || isdigit(arrayBuf[0])){
                for(int a = 1; a < strlen(arrayBuf); a ++){
                    if(!isdigit(arrayBuf[a])){
                        if(arrayBuf[a] == !f2) f2 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
            if(f2 = false){
                printf("The elements are not integers\n");
                return 4;
            }
            
            if (c = count) break;
            arrayBuf = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

        //Summary of arrays
        int sum[m][n];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j ++){
                sum[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        
        int schet;
        if (f1 = false){
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i ++){
                for(int j = 0; j < m; j ++){
                    for(int g = 0; g < n; g ++){
                        sum[j][g] += numbers[schet++];
                        arrayBuf = strtok(NULL, " ");
                        if (arrayBuf == NULL) break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i ++){
                for(int g = 0; g < n; g ++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < m; j ++){
                        sum[j][g] += numbers[schet++];
                        arrayBuf = strtok(NULL, " ");
                        if(arrayBuf == NULL) break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j ++){
                printf("%d\n", sum[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
    free(buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `assert()` на аргументы, `getopt()` и позиционные аргументы вперемешку... там чистить и вычищать!

Comment: Потом, замените `strtok()` на `strsep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте конструкцию:

```
if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open the file\n");
        return 2;
    }
```

так:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open the file '%s'\n", name);
        perror("Error");
        return 2;
    }
```

И причина станет очевидной.